# How can I launch Jupyter Notebook in Safari?

Tags: python, safari, jupyter-notebook

I am on a Mac OS, and my default browser is Firefox.

In terminal, I ran `jupyter notebook --generate-config`. Then, in a text editor, I opened ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py

I changed `c.NotebookApp.browser = u''` to `c.NotebookApp.browser = u'/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari %s'`

However, when I run `jupyter notebook`, I get the following output:

````
```
[I 15:14:23.717 NotebookApp] [nb_conda_kernels] enabled, 3 kernels found
[I 15:14:24.586 NotebookApp] [nb_anacondacloud] enabled
[I 15:14:24.589 NotebookApp] [nb_conda] enabled
[I 15:14:24.626 NotebookApp] ✓ nbpresent HTML export ENABLED
[W 15:14:24.626 NotebookApp] ✗ nbpresent PDF export DISABLED: No module named nbbrowserpdf.exporters.pdf
[I 15:14:24.632 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/ironaut/Tutorials/DAND/Jupyter
[I 15:14:24.632 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 15:14:24.632 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/?token=74a348c3fdec07e929dde216c244e1a9164badc47f079819
[I 15:14:24.632 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
Failed to acquire exclusive access to history store at file:///Users/ironaut/Library/Safari/History.db. Falling back to an in-memory history store.
[W 15:22:55.201 NotebookApp] 401 POST /login?next=%2Ftree%3F (::1) 1.30ms referer=http://localhost:8888/login?next=%2Ftree%3F
```
````

Without the changes to the config file, jupyter launches okay in Firefox.

Comment: If you think my answer solved your problem, request you to accept it as the answer so that others will know that my solution works.

Comment: Jupyter notebook will be opened in default browser unless you change in the config file

Answer (score 14):

You almost had all steps. Re-iterating for the benefit of the readers.

Make sure that `firefox` is the default browser. Or any other browser for that matter.

I am using `atom` as text editor. Feel free to use any other.

Execute

```
$ jupyter notebook --generate-config
$ atom ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

find and change

```
c.NotebookApp.browser = u''
```

to

```
c.NotebookApp.browser = u'/usr/bin/open -a Safari %s'
```

Test

```
$ jupyter notebook
```

Comment: If this fixed your problem, it's customary to accept the answer so others know it worked and so the person who helped you gets awarded points for it.

Answer (score 0):

Open: vim .jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py

find > c.NotebookApp.ip = ‘localhost’
Change > c.NotebookApp.ip = ‘127.0.0.1’

Remove the # sign at the beginning, though.